# change border color on custom color

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uicolor

I v got UITextView, and I want to set it a new custom color like this

```
    var instaColor = UIColor(red: 51, green: 92, blue: 131, alpha: 1).CGColor

    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    textView.layer.borderColor = instaColor
```

but its color is white or not appear at all, whats with this? this color should be dark blue + green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIColor requires the color values to be between 0 and 1 so you should change it to:

```
var instaColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 92/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

In the above you are dividing each value by 255 to get the color value to between 0 and 1.

I think your code should work after you do that.

Thanks

Comment: No problem, I was stuck on the same topic a few days ago.. I am glad I helped!